# MFC: Why is the Accelerator not working?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I am trying to use an accelerator in a class that inherits from `CFrameWnd`, which itself is used in a class that inherits from `CWinApp`. For some reason the shortcuts I defined in the accelerator just don't want to work.

There are two classes: `CMyFrame` (inherits from `CFrameWnd`) and `CMyApp` (inherits from `CWinApp`).

Relevant functions:

```
BOOL CMyApp::InitInstance() {
    m_hAccel = LoadAccelerators(AfxGetInstanceHandle(), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_ACCELERATOR1));

    CMyFrame *Frame = new CMyFrame();
    m_pMainWnd = Frame;

    Frame->ShowWindow(SW_NORMAL);
    Frame->UpdateWindow();

    return TRUE;
}

BOOL CMyApp::ProcessMessageFilter(int code, LPMSG Msg) {
    if (m_hAccel) {
        if (::TranslateAccelerator(m_pMainWnd->m_hWnd, m_hAccel, Msg)) {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
    return CWinApp::ProcessMessageFilter(code, Msg);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyFrame, CFrameWnd)
    ON_COMMAND(ID_FILE_NEW, &CMyFrame::OnFileNew)
    ON_COMMAND(ID_FILE_SAVE, &CMyFrame::OnFileSave)
    ON_COMMAND(ID_EDIT_CUT, &CMyFrame::OnEditCut)
    ON_COMMAND(ID_EDIT_COPY, &CMyFrame::OnEditCopy)
    ON_COMMAND(ID_EDIT_PASTE, &CMyFrame::OnEditPaste)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void CMyFrame::OnFileNew() {
    MessageBox(L"OnFileNew", L"Event", MB_OK);
}

void CMyFrame::OnFileSave() {
    MessageBox(L"OnFileSave", L"Event", MB_OK);
}

void CMyFrame::OnEditCut() {
    MessageBox(L"OnEditCut", L"Event", MB_OK);
}

void CMyFrame::OnEditCopy() {
    MessageBox(L"OnEditCopy", L"Event", MB_OK);
}

void CMyFrame::OnEditPaste() {
    MessageBox(L"OnEditPaste", L"Event", MB_OK);
}
```

I  included `afxwin.h` and `resource.h`.
The accelerator itself is loaded correctly (I checked the return value using another messagebox. It was always 1 and MSDN states that every value except for 0 means success). Also when I do not load the accelerator the menu items are greyed out.
The items themselves are also working correctly. When I click them the corresponding messagebox pops up.
The header of `CMyFrame` contains the `DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CFrameWnd` has its own [`CFrameWnd::LoadAccelTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0kba7ctw.aspx) method. Add this line:

```
Frame->LoadAccelTable(MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_ACCELERATOR1));
```

`CWinThread::ProcessMessageFilter` will process accelerator messages if MFC dialog box is active. But the way it is set up in your code, it will pass the accelerator to the main frame, not dialog box.

Comment: Thank you a lot. For some reason last time I tried that it did not work. This time I placed the call in `CMyFrame::InitInstance()` just before the `Frame->ShowWindow(SW_NORMAL)` and it worked!